# How does asyncio enable parallel IO waits?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to understand how `asyncio` allows for multiple IO waits to happen in parallel. It is often said that `asyncio` enables *concurrency*, but not *parallelism*. From what I understand, this is true for Python code as such, but **something** must be happening in parallel, otherwise the execution time would still be the sum of its parts? That something is presumably waiting for IO.

The [generic example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) uses `sleep` - we have two tasks sleeping, at least conceptually, *in parallel*.

Other tutorials use `aiohttp` to run multiple HTTP requests *concurrently*, presumably with many of them waiting on their data *in parallel*. But how is it done? How is a (blocking) read initiated and then control relinquished until it's done? I imagine the actual parallelism happens at the OS level, or maybe some underying C library, but I don't know how to express that in Python.

What happens under the hood (e.g. in `aiohttp`)?

Comment: This is a great talk: https://youtu.be/MCs5OvhV9S4

Comment: +1 for the talk linked by mkrieger1. A good rule of thumb is that "threads are for working in parallel, and async is for waiting in parallel". Asyncio funnels all the individual awaits initiated by coroutines to a single OS-level poll that waits for a lot of stuff in parallel. Whenever something happens, asyncio dispatches the event by resuming the coroutine that registered interest in that event in its "await".